# Setting state to and item in an array passed from child to grandparent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of items in a cart, I would like to set the state for each item. I have successfully update/pass state from child to parent and update grandparent, but once there is more than one item in the cart, the state is not being set per item.

here is an example of my products

```
[
{
"id": 2630,
"name": "Fried Chicken Sandwich",
"product_id": 321,
"quantity": 1,
"total": "50.00",
“options”:  “”
},
{
"id": 2629,
"name": "Beef Burger",
"product_id": 320,
"quantity": 1,
"total": "50.00",
“options”:  “”
},
]
```

here is an example of the code in ProductItem.js, the child component used to update "options" when the user has entered the item options (e.g. no onions) for their order.

```
this.state = {
fromChild: ""
};

<TextInput
value={this.state.fromChild}
placeholder="Options"
onChangeText={(fromChild) => this.setState({ fromChild })}
style={styles.optionsInput}
/>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.update(this.state.fromChild)}>
<Text>Save order options</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

My parent component MyCart.js looks like this

```
this.state = {
fromParent: null,
};

{cartItems.map((item, index) => (
<ProductItem
key={index.toString()}
product={item.product}
update={this.props.update}
/>))
}
```

MY grandparent component, ShopCart.js is receiving the adopted data perfectly, except, the state is being duplicated for each item, where i want each item's state to be set based on its index

```
this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
this.state = {
orderData: null,
};


updateState = (itemOption) => {
this.setState({ orderData: `${itemOption}` })
}


<MyCart
update={this.updateState}
/>
```

**This is what i am currently getting for options**

```
[
{
"id": 2630,
"name": "Fried Chicken Sandwich",
"product_id": 321,
"quantity": 1,
"total": "50.00",
“options”:  “no onions”
},
{
"id": 2629,
"name": "Beef Burger",
"product_id": 320,
"quantity": 1,
"total": "50.00",
“options”:  “no onions”
}
```

**Only one item should have no onions**

```
[
{
"id": 2630,
"name": "Fried Chicken Sandwich",
"product_id": 321,
"quantity": 1,
"total": "50.00",
“options”:  “no onions”
},
{
"id": 2629,
"name": "Beef Burger",
"product_id": 320,
"quantity": 1,
"total": "50.00",
“options”:  “”
},
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated!